# Does sister Mary pass with rolls of 3-6 when Blessed and 5-6 when Cursed?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-under-the-pyramids

The faq says

> Sister Mary and each other investigator on her space adds 1 to the result of each die rolled as part of an effect printed on a Condition card that has the BANE or BOON trait. This modification applies whether the die is rolled as part of a test or not.

(Yes I see the grammar error with "adds" in there.)

I know this applies to testing whether to keep or discard the cards on a reckoning, but do we get to add 1 also to all tests and effective nullify the Curse and boost the Blessed to allow rolls of 3-6 as successes? This just seems so powerful!

Answer (score 1):

> *adds 1 to the result rolled **as part of an effect printed on a Condition card** that has the BANE or BOON trait*

Not all tests in the game are printed on the Boon or Bane cards.

Comment: Yes but all tests are affected by the Blessed's effect which is printed on its card saying "4s 5s and 6s count as successes on your tests", so are dice rolled from THOSE tests "part" of that aspect of the Blessed's effect? That's essentially my question.

Comment: They're affected by boon effect - yes. But they are not rolled as part of a boon effect.

Comment: Why would the faq clarify that the modification applies whether it is a test or not? There are no tests on the bane/boon cards, only rolls to discard the cards on a reckoning. That makes me think they may be implying to use it for the tests affected by these cards. Otherwise what would people be applying it to? It doesn't seem the faq question was intended to clarify to people to use it for the reckoning effect discard.

Comment: There are no tests on the *existing* bane/boon cards.